# suggest which logging( tool /framework) should be used for java,j2ee project

Tags: logging

I am using following technology stack in my java j2ee project please suggest an appropriate logging framework

JSF 1.1
EJB 3.0
JPA 1.1

Answer (score 1):

to give a more verbal response.
most frameworks come to fulfill some need or as a solution to some problem.
If you are just starting off a small application and you need to log some files I would go with a simple and reliable solution like log4j or alternatively [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) which can be connected to many different implementations including log4j (it's from the same author)

I myself used log4j for several years and found that it evolved well as the needs of my company grew, you can also extend it for more advanced functionality later on as you might want asynchronous logging or logging via syslog (all already implemented in log4j).

If you have some very specific use case for which you feel this is too simple feel free to detail it.

Answer (score -1):

One of the simplest way of logging is [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/)

Comment: Please edit this post so that it contains more than just a link. See the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information.